# What do I need to start developing Android applications using java and eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

What do I need, using java and eclipse, to do Android development?

Comment: no (eclipse), but it's a lot easier/funner if you do.

Answer (score 2):

If you download and installer Eclipse Classic from here:
[Eclipse Classic Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-362/heliossr2) The download links for all platforms are to the right.

And then follow this guide to install Android SDK:
[Installing Android SDK](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#installation_androidsdk)

Then you will be up and running in no time. :)
Otherwise just return here, if you have any questions :)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta - Sorry, old habits are hard to break.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

This is the official guide about how to setup your computer for android development. There's also links about how to start writing your first application after you have everything set up.